# Need advice in tree implementation. Sort Set by Field or Natural order with sorted copy

Tags: java, sorting, user-interface, tree

Doing some implementation of GUI, i stuck with problem.


Currently, I'm using `TreeSet` for storing `childNodes` in UI Tree. And for convinience/perfomance sake I ordered this set by Z-layer of UI(so that top most `widget` will eat event first)

And I can't decide what to use for holding Children, my ideas is:

1. (Current) `TreeSet` ordered by Z, but because Z of different
   `Widgets` can be equal, my `CompareTo` method is assymetrical, so
   that's wrong.
2. Make `TreeSet` with natural order, and create
       sorted by Z copy for event handling and rendering. This should be
       better
3. Make Sorted Array that will be checked for duplicates
       when child is added to Widget

I'm hesitating because in first scenario I update Set only if Z-value is changed. 

But in second case I must make Copy of Set then Sort it in each cycle or have second array of children that resorted when necessary

Third option is most simple, not sure if there might be problems

I'm hoping for some advice

**PS.** Third option came into my mind while i was typing it. I think it might be the answer, but I'll post this question anyways.

**PS2** Option 4: make Z layer unique would make everything much easier, because on each Z-layer must be only one Widget, otherwise what the should do? cancel each other? So I'll probably stick with this

Comment: Can't you keep your TreeSet ordered by Z, but add another criteria to determine the order when two Widgets have equal Z?

Comment: It's an option too,  having time when it was put into collection or something like that